# CASE statement in a SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Originally, I was building the Search string in C# and using that to search the DB, but I am starting to switch it to use Stored Procedures. What I am trying to do is that when the @DeletedDeviceSearch variable is false, it adds 'LogicallYDeleted = 0' into the search string otherwise it searches for both Logically deleted devices and current devices.

I am having trouble with the `WHERE` clause. I believe that a CASE statement is the way to go, but I am not sure how to configure it... Any Help is appreciated

Below is the code:

```
USE Inventory;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo.InventorySearch] 
    @FieldName nvarchar(50), 
    @SearchTerm nvarchar(50)
    @DeletedDeviceSearch bit
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT LK_User, LK_Location, DeviceName, AssetTypeId, DeviceID, SerialNumber, LogicallyDeleted
FROM Device 
WHERE 

(CASE(@DeviceSearch) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 
        LogicallyDeleted = 0 and  @FieldName = @SearchTerm

        ELSE @FieldName = @SearchTerm)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `where` clause, there's better ways to go but a `case`. You could write your `where` clause like this:

```
WHERE 
   (@DeviceSearch = 1 and LogicallyDeleted = 0 and @FieldName = @SearchTerm) OR
   (@DeviceSearch <> 1 and @FieldName = @SearchTerm)
```

However, if you *really* want to use the `case` statement, please note that `case` returns a value, and does not execute something. So it must read like this:

```
WHERE
  LogicallyDeleted = CASE WHEN @DeviceSearch = 1 THEN 0 ELSE LogicallyDeleted END AND
  @FieldName = @SearchTerm
```

The trick here is that `LogicallyDeleted` is only compared to 0 if `@DeviceSearch = 1`. In every other case, `LogicallyDeleted` is compared to itself, which always returns true.

So, if `@DeviceSearch` is not 1, the `where` clause reads like this:

```
WHERE LogicallyDeleted = LogicallyDeleted AND @FieldName = @SearchTerm
```

If `@DeviceSearch` is 1, the `where` clause reads like this:

```
WHERE LogicallyDeleted = 0 AND @FieldName = @SearchTerm
```

Comment: I really appreciate the quick answer. The  explanation of how the code works is extremely helpful as well...

Answer (score 0):

Because this SP is used for search purpose (therefore SPEEEED and accuracy are mandatory) I would create the SP content like so:

IF (@DeviceSearch = 1)
BEGIN
 SELECT LK_User, LK_Location, DeviceName, AssetTypeId, DeviceID, SerialNumber, LogicallyDeleted
  FROM Device 
  WHERE LogicallyDeleted = 0 and @FieldName = @SearchTerm
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SELECT LK_User, LK_Location, DeviceName, AssetTypeId, DeviceID, SerialNumber, LogicallyDeleted
  FROM Device 
  WHERE @FieldName = @SearchTerm
END

I know that this is more difficult to maintain and the select statemens "look" redundant but this way is faster..

Comment: BTW, shouldn't you use like in the condition(s) ? ... @FieldName like '%' + <SearchTerm> + '%'

Comment: Why would that be faster?

Comment: I know that conditions logically "connected" with OR are not so good for performance. So in this particular case I was suggesting the above alternative, trying to avoid using OR-ed conditions. I guess there is something that can be added to the else branch select statement's where clause in my case, an extra condition AND LogicallyDeleted <> 0.

Comment: I don't think you can generally say that OR conditions are slower. Still you suggest using `LIKE`. I'd say using `LIKE` (which prevents the use of an index on that column) slows down things *waaays* worse than using `OR` :-)

Comment: The "like" comment was just a side note given the functionality of the SP. I am familiar with the (huge) negative impact of the % wildcard used at the beginning.. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Well, you were right suggesting it (unless the OP expects to be searching for full content only). I just never came to think to write a stored procedure like you suggest just to avoid an OR. If the OR was on a table field, I'd say you're right. However, this OR depends solely on the value of a SP parameter and should thus not have that much of a negative impact.